# I have some problem with Retrieving the data from firebase realtimedatabase,I can't retrieve data through "getPosts" function,tell the correct version

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i91md.png)

I can't retrieve data through "getPosts" function,Please tell the correct version of getPosts

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading an image.